# Compare variances between two populations with different means

Tags: r, mean, variance

I would like to compare two populations which have different means. I want to find a way to compare their variances, to have an idea of which of the two populations have values that disperse further from the mean.

The issues is that I think I should need a variance standardized/normalized on the mean value of each distribution.

Suggestions?

The next step would be to get a function in R that it is able to do that.

Comment: you can try `var.test()`

Comment: Ok, may be it is what I was looking for. However, I'm looking for a formula to  have the empirical value of variance of the two distributions given the mean values of each.

Comment: you can try Kolmogorov-Smirnov test or Fligner-Killeen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to standardise/normalise because variance is calculated as distance from the mean so is already normalised around the sample mean.

To demonstrate this run the following code

```
x<-runif(10000,min=100,max=101)
y<-runif(10000,min=1,max=2)
mean(x)
mean(y)
var(x)
var(y)
```

You'll see while the mean is different the variance of the two samples is identical (allowing for some difference due to pseudo-random number generation and sample size)

Comment: yes, but if for example you have a distribution with mean 0.90, so it has a lot of values at a distance of 0.01 from the mean, and then we have a distribution with mean 0.01 with a lot of samples at a distance of 0.01. In those two cases the dispersion of the distributions is not the same. The first will more tight the second more large.

Comment: 0.89, 0.90, 0.91 will have the same variance as 0.00,0.01,0.02. Variance is calculated as sum of squared euclidean distances of observation from the mean so it's relative to the mean, you don't need to normalise. I think your thinking variance is a percentage distance from the mean and it's not.

Comment: Ok. I'm convinced. However, your last comments brought me to another discussion that nobody has been able to answer and it is not clear in the web. That is how we compute a normalised Euclidean distance. In another case I will have to compare to frequency distributions. And I think that in this  case I need a normalised distance metric (as you said a percentage distance).

Comment: Euclidean distance just means straight line distance so doesn't need normalising e.g. 100-150 is the same as 1450-1500. If you want to compare the frequency distribution of observations on the same x-axis scale you could subtract the mean from each observation X and divide by the standard deviation (sqrt of variance). Hard to know if this is what your after thought without seeing your data.

Comment: Yes I think this what i was looking for and its names id the normalised Euclidean distance right?

Comment: Yes your right, sorry I wasn't aware it was called that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128943/discussion-between-caffesospeso-and-morganball).